# SSIS Package 2005 - dynamic ToLine

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence

I need to route an email using the Send Mail Task, in SSIS 2005 depending on a variable within a script task.

So, far, I've created a Variable in the variables tab, but can't seem to figure out where to set it, or how to access it using the code.

Apologies for the vague question, but this isn't my bag, and i'm trying to help out another team. I can send through more detail if required.

[image: Script task with a Send Mail Task]

[image: Variable within the Variable tab]

```
Public Function SetEmailAddress(ByVal variable x As String) As String
if x = y then set the isConfirmation variable.
```

The little code snippet above, is what i'm trying to achieve within the Script Task - process file object.

Comment: Based on the value of `isConfirmation` you will send it to A@foo.com or b@foo.com. The Script task sets the value of isConfirmation and your question is how do I make the Send Mail Task behave differently based on it?

Comment: Hi, i cant seem to set the isConfirmation dynamically. I think i've figured out that i'd need an Expression on the Send Mail object, something like @User::isConfirmation ? address1 : address2

Comment: just to add, there also appears an corresponding xml file, called projectname.dtsConfig, which has the \PackageVariables[User::address.... Oddly, my isConfirmation variable doesn't show after saving the project.

Comment: You are correct on the Expression part. So the real question becomes: how do I modify the value of an SSIS Variable in a Script Task?

Comment: Indeed, that appears to be the problem. However, my logic seems correct, but perhaps, i'm not implementing it correctly.

Comment: The .dtsConfig file is configuration file that supplies values for the package. This allows you to make value changes external to the package without editing (Server A becomes Server b in stage and Server C in production). Things only get into that file when you explicitly add them (which is a separate question)

Comment: right, thought as much... lets plays devils advocate then, and say, if script variable is true, then set the ToLine to a node in the xml file. I therefore, have for arguments sake User::address1 and User::address2 both with the email address i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a copy of the 2005 SSIS release handy, so some of this answer is approximate.

The big picture what you will need to do is modify the `.Value` of an object in the SSIS 
Variables collection.

### Setting Variable's value via code

With 2008+, they modified the editor so you can specify that you're going to access SSIS Variables. I can't recall if they made that available in 2005. Based on [Jamie's](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/02/09/SSIS_3A00_-Writing-to-a-variable-from-a-script-task.aspx) post, it looks like it was available. So, you can either use a GUI if it's available to indicate you want to modify the value of `isConfirmation` or you can go through the lock/unlock process below

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Public Class ScriptMain
  Public Sub Main()
    Dim vars As Variables
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("isConfirmation", vars)
    ' Assign a boolean value to the thing we just locked for modifying
    vars(0).Value = (x=y)
    vars.Unlock()
    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
  End Sub
End Class
```

If you use the GUI to indicate you're locking the variable, it'd be approximately

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Public Class ScriptMain
  Public Sub Main()
    ' Update it in place
    Dts.Variables("isConfirmation").Value = (x=y)
    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
  End Sub
End Class
```

Even though you're in VB which is not case sensitive, the base SSIS object model is case sensitive so IsConfirmation is not going to be found in the Variables collection.

### Putting it all together

Assuming you have three SSIS Variables created, isConfirmation - boolean and two String variables Address1 and Address2. When isConfirmation is true, we wish to use Address1. When false, we want to use Address2.

You can create the expression directly on the object but you can't debug that. Instead, create *another* variable, FinalAddress of type string. Right click on it and in the properties menu, set the EvaluateAsExpression property to True and in the Expression use the following formula `@[User::isConfirmation] ? @[User::Address1] : @[User::Address2]`

Then, on the Send Mail Task itself, set the ToLine (approximate) to be `@[User::FinalAddress]`

### Troubleshooting

According to the comments, there are problems when the package is run at the server. In cases like this, I'd look to raise some event messages from the package.

```
    Dim fireAgain As Boolean = True
    Dim isCurrent As Boolean = True
    ' logic here
    ' report on status of what we care about
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Debug", String.Format("isCurrent = {0}", isCurrent), String.Empty, 0, ByRef fireAgain)
```

When you call the package, either through agent or the command line, you're going to want to make sure the `/REPORTING E` parameter becomes `/REPORTING EIW` (to report errors, warnings and information events. Rarely is it a bad practice to log this information as it is)

Comment: thanks billinkc, i shall give this a bash and test in the morning. Many thanks

Comment: If you or your teammates don't already have [Bids Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) grab it and install. It makes SSIS work far more pleasant experience, especially on pre-2012 releases

Comment: Cheers - will definitely take a look.

Comment: Hi billinkc, if i run through in Business Studio, and manually change the isConfirmation from True to false, and then click the Send email task i can see the email address changing as expected. However, when it's deployed (Just copied the dtsx file into DTS folder), the recipients are incorrect. basically it looks like the logic isn't working.

Comment: I added the section on troubleshooting. See where that gets you.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like its something to do with the way the package is being deployed/initially set up. I've made some hard coded changes to the email text, which doesn't show either. Plus, I've totally removed a recipients email address, and after copy/paste of the dtsx file, he still receives emails :-)

Comment: Of course, it might help if I was deploying it to the correct server :-)