# .BAT File not kicking off SSIS Package

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I have a .BAT file that kicked off a simple SSIS package.(Destination to Source) worked great. I have updated my SSIS package to only include partical loading which now is quite a bigger process. This works perfectly but now it does not run under the .BAT file. Errors below, thoughts?

Why would the .bat not run after changes? Is there limitations on types of processes from SSIS that a .bat can run?

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "Q:\D783\F11701\SECURED\MCS Analytics\Projects\JXM1563_SSIS\SironHealth\SironHealth\Package.dtsx" /REP EIW > C:\temp\packagelog.txt
```

Errors and Warnings:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 11.0.6020.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Started:  8:44:26 AM
Error: 2017-03-29 08:44:28.82
Code: 0xC000F427
Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Dest Lookup Match of Integration Services or higher.
End Error
Error: 2017-03-29 08:44:28.82
Code: 0xC000F427
Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Lookup of Integration Services or higher.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  8:44:26 AM
Finished: 8:44:28 AM
Elapsed:  2.418 seconds
```

Comment: Please log the output to see if there are any errors.  Add something like this to your command `> c:\temp\packagelog.txt`

Comment: I can add this command under my exist text?

Comment: Yes, just make sure the path exists.  Please check the output for errors and update your question if needed.

Comment: Also add the options of `/rep EIW` to Mark's suggestion (thus dtexec /f Path/To/Dtsx /rep EIW > log.txt  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/23895854/181965

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "Q:\D783\Projects\lth\Package.dtsx/rep EIW > log.txt

>
Q:\D783\Projects\lth\packagelog.tx

Comment: I'm not seeing a log file from the above batch file that I created. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If no log file is created at all, then the batch file isn't being called. If the log file is empty, and what you provided is verbatim, then the package ran without errors. If you add `/rep EIW` that will ensure Errors, Informational, and Warning messages are reported to the console - which are then redirected to the text file via `>`

Comment: Step 1: Log on to server where package should be run. Step 2: copy the entire command from batch file. Step 3: Open a command prompt (Windows-R cmd) and paste the command from step 2

Comment: Doing the above, will get you the closest to seeing what is happening without any "oddness" in the way.

Comment: @billinkc My problem is I'm not sure I have the syntax correct. Can you look at the updated question and review my .BAT?  Were does /rep EIW go?

Comment: @billinkc Also, I copy and pasted the script into cmd and is show errors. But I'm focused on catpuring the log file and storing the log file to the path.

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" 
/f "Q:\D783\F11701\SECURED\CSnics\Projects\JX_SSIS\th\Silth\Package.dtsx" /REP EIW  > C:\temp\packagelog.txt

Comment: @billinkc That worked thanks. Now to solve the errors!

Comment: The error you are now capturing indicates that the [SSIS components are not installed on the server](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49786/error-to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install) that is executing the package